# Bind computed string to User Control in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have ASP.NET User Control and want to pass formatted string as argument:

```
<UI:SomeControl runat="server" 
     Visible="<%# IsControlVisible %>"
     Caption="Caption string"
     OnClick=<%# string.Format("someFunction({0}, {1}", 1, 2) %>
/>
```

Here is code of **SomeControl.aspx.cs**:

```
public partial class SomeControl: UserControl
    {
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public string Hint { get; set; }
        public string OnClick { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Everything is OK when just some field (`<%# SomeField1 #>`) or constant string (like Caption in example) is passed. But nothing is added when I want to make string from values of several fields (like in my example): `OnClick` is null.

How should I properly pass computed string to User Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a public property in the User Control you can then set if from the parent.

On the UC

```
public string myVariable { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabelOnUserControl.Text = myVariable;
}
```

And then on the parent page you can set that value by setting the public property.

```
SomeControl.myVariable = "ValueFromParent";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to set that property right from ASPX Web Page, not from C# code

Comment: Then what do you mean by "computed string" exactly? And `OnClick` is not a property of a UserControl, even with the quotes.

Comment: `OnClick` property has already existed on `SomeControl` type, I've added SomeControl source code to the question. 
By "computed string" I mean "set result of function as the value of `SomeControl`'s property. And I want to write this function not in C# code, but right in the control's tag in ASPX markup.

Comment: Your problem is probably the page life cyle: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx. The User Control has finished loading before you chage the variable of OnClick. So you if you do not want to load the user controls dynamically or create a method in the UC that sets the value by calling that method from code behind you are stuck. To put it simply the Page Load of the UC comes before the method triggered by a PostBack on the parent page.

Comment: The problem is I stil get nothing even if I write `OnClick=<%# (string.Format("1")) %>`. I.e. I don't depend on any properties of page.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to trigger some JavaScript (`someFunction(1, 2)`) when a user has clicked on your custom user control, and the parameters that are being passed into the JavaScript should be populated by some values determined on the server...

You can try the following (first give your user control a unique ID that can be referenced in your code behind);

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    myControl.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("someJsFunctionName({0},{1});", a, b);
}
```

This can be placed inside `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` or any other part of the [page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) once your `a` and `b` values have been established.